# Is it good programming practice to create my Destructors?

Tags: c++, destructor, explicit-destructor-call

My c++ book says that a Destructor "is automatically called when an object is destroyed". So is it considered good or bad practice to create one if I am not planning to have any code like the below example within it?

The example from my book is:

```
Demo::~Demo()
{
    cout << "Now the destructor is running.\n";
}
```

Comment: If you don't write one, the compiler will provide you with an empty one automatically. If you need (or want) to do something special, then write one. If you need to write a destructor, please be aware of the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) as you will likely also need to write additional constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: The compiler will automatically generate a destructor for you. You should write your own if/when the generated one does not do what you need it to.

Comment: Creating a destructor like you have shown is only good practice if you need to see how destructors are called in your application. Other than that, it serves no purpose.

Comment: @SidS, can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Sid S I'd say such a claim requires a proving example.

Comment: @SidS Could you provide an example on https://godbolt.org/ ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: I must have been time-travelling back to the early nineties or something.  No, I could not come up with an example using my current toolchain.

Answer (score 4):

Remember the [rule of three](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

The rule of three (also known as the Law of The Big Three or The Big Three) is a rule of thumb in C++ (prior to C++11) that claims that if a class defines one (or more) of the following it should probably explicitly define all three:[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

- destructor
- copy constructor
- copy assignment operator

Comment: Also remember the rule of 5 and the rule of zero.

Comment: An explicit destructor is usually only needed if the class dynamically allocated resources that need to be freed at time of destruction. And a better option in most such cases is to use containers or smart pointers that automatically release their contained resources - no explicit destructor required.

Comment: @JesperJuhl not really. True, dynamically allocated resources would be the one case which would require destructor, but there are others. Easiest to imagine would be a class which counts the number of it's instances. The rule of 5 is golden. No matter how hard I try, I can't come up with a case where sane class needs a sane copy constructor, but doesn't need a destructor.

Comment: @Jesper: Joining threads, closing sockets, writing "footers" to open files, flushing buffers (not C++ file streams! other types of buffers) are all good reasons to write your own destructor. Destructors are not _just_ for memory management. You _did_ say "usually" rather than "always" but I still think your comment is a little misleading.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - I *know* that. Maybe you didn't notice that I wrote "... dynamically allocated resources that need to be freed  ..." - such resources need of course not be *memory*, they could be (almost) anything. What is your point? Threads to join, sockets, etc I all consider dynamically allocated resources. Writing footers, no, not dynamic resources, but if you want that it's pretty damn obvious you want to do that in a dtor.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: My point is exactly what I said: I think your comment is a little misleading. Don't need to get so defensive.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - didn't mean to get defensive. Perhaps I misunderstood you. All I tried to say was "if you have something you need to do (free) when your class dies, you need a destructor" if you don't (and it's often easy to arange that you don't), then no destructor is needed.